# Assigning Visible Property of the Button to a Static Method Result

Tags: css, asp.net, .net

I am trying to hide the button based on the user's role using the following code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btndisplayrole" Text="Admin Button" Visible='<%= WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DisplayRoleClick" />
```

But when I run the above code I get the following error message:

Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin") %>' for the 'Visible'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kind of an interesting issue.. But as the error message states, the string `<%= WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin") %>` cannot be converted to a boolean.

Unfortunately i cannot explain why the expression isn't evaluated, but instead is treated like a string.

The reason why your `<%# %>` expression works as expected, is because it is treated much differently. When the Page is compiled into a class, then the compiler creates an event handler similar to this:

```
public void __DataBindingButton2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button) sender;
    Page bindingContainer = (Page) button.BindingContainer;
    button.Visible = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin");
}
```

and hooks this method up to the Control.Databinding event on your control. As you can see, the `<%# %>` is this time properly treated as server code, and not just a random string.

So i guess the solution is either to use databinding, or go to the codebehind as AndreasKnudsen suggests.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative solution:

```xml
<% if (WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
    {%>
        <asp:Button ID="btndisplayrole" 
                    Text="Admin Button" 
                    runat="server" 
                    OnClick="DisplayRoleClick" /> 
<%} %>
```

Comment: +1 for posting an workaround about the visibility but I guess the OP would like to make it work for any other control property.

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked:

```
Visible='<%# WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin") %>'
```

Note that the aboe use the binding expression!

Comment: Actually the above code is NOT what I needed since now I have to bind the page in order to execute the code!

Answer (score 2):

how about just doing it in the codebehind, for instance on Page_Load ?

```
public void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   btndisplayrole.Visible = WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Visible='<%= WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin").ToString() %>'
```

OR

```
Visible=<%= WebApplication1.SiteHelper.IsUserInRole("Admin") %>
```

Comment: Tried both of them none of them worked. IsUserInRole return booleon.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wrote my reply based on the error that you are getting.