# How do I make my ASP.NET server control take an embedded code block as a property value?

Tags: asp.net, web-controls, servercontrols

I have a custom server control with a property of Title.  When using the control, I'd like to set the value of the title in the aspx page like so:

```
<cc1:customControl runat="server" Title='<%= PagePropertyValue%>' >
more content
</cc1:customControl>
```

When I do this, however, I am getting the exact String <%= PagePropertyValue%> being displayed rather than the Property Value that I would like to see.

So after trying the databinding expression (as suggested below).  I don't get the string literal that looked bad but I don't get anything else either.

```
<cc1:customControl runat="server" Title='<%# PagePropertyValue%>' >
more content
</cc1:customControl>
```

What do I need to do to my custom control to take this sort of value? Or is there something I need to do to the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant. <%= %> will write the string directly to the response-stream, which happens after the server control is constructed. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-compile) for an explanation.

So its either codebehind, or <%# + databinding as Zachary suggests.

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to my own question, I have discovered that what I really wanted was to use ASP.NET Expressions using the <%$ syntax, since what I wanted to do was put in localized content.

This can be done with apparently no extra handling on the server control side.

```
<cc1:customControl runat="server" Title='<%$ Resouces: ResourceFile, ContentKey %>' >
more content and controls
</cc1:customControl>
```

This works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using databinding syntax:
`<%# PagePropertyValue %>`

Comment: That made it display blank rather than the actual code string.  I am not implementing a databinding event on my control.   I get similar results with an asp label control with both settings. (using text property).

Comment: Try call label.DataBind() and it should display whatever the expression returns.

Answer (score 1):

For the bind property value to work correctly as suggested, you will have this in the aspx or ascx file :

```
<cc1:customControl runat="server" Title='<%# PagePropertyValue %>' >
more content
</cc1:customControl>
```

You will then need to actually bind data in your page wich you have to add this in you code behind file (code in C#)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

That way it will bind the data in your ascx or aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is specific to control attributes. When using the <%= syntax outside control attributes meaning anywhere else in the page the syntax works as expected. So this
    
        <%=GetCapitalUserName()%>
    
would call the correct method and inject the result of the call in the page.