# Code block + literal in asp.net custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm searching for 2 days now to accomplish the following:
I want a custom control which will take inline text + code blocks.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
<asp:MyCustom runat="server">
    Hello there, <%= User.Name%>
</asp:MyCustom>
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
[ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(true)]
public class MyCustom
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public ITemplate Text { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public MyCustom()
    {
        Text = new StringITemplate(text);
    }
}
```

On top of that, the control is actually a member of a list of a parent user control that inherits from "UserControl", overrides the Render method. Also, there is a class StringITemplate, which allows assigning plain strings to the ITemplate property as well.

Ultimately, I want to achieve the following:

```
<asp:MyCustomItemControl runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:Item>Hello there, <%= User.Name%></asp:Item>
        <asp:Item><%= SomeOtherString%></asp:Item>
    </Items>
</asp:MyCustom>
```

Right now, I would be happy if my first request actually worked. Seems like hell to get a grip on the wilderness of web/user/custom/server - controls in asp.net and their properties.

The complete code of what I have right now, can be looked at here:
http://pastebin.com/3gic2Y0u

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for something like this.

I found this answer here, which answered it for me:

[How do I make my ASP.NET server control take an embedded code block as a property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387167/how-do-i-make-my-asp-net-server-control-take-an-embedded-code-block-as-a-propert)

A summary of the answer is:
`<%=` type codeblocks are intended to be feed directly to the streamwriter.  Instead, use `<%#` codeblock and include

> This.DataBind()

in the `Page_Init` of the `Item` class.