# Binding via <% on .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, binding

Is there any difference between performing binding on .aspx page via <%# some code %> and <%= some code %>?

Example:

> 

VS

> 

Thanks.
-Igor

Comment: +close, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<%# %>` is used in *binding expressions*. Simply, when a `Control.DataBind` is called, the binding expressions will take their actual values. It can be used to set some properties on server controls based on the run time value of an expression.

`<%= expression %>` is equivalent to `<% Response.Write(expression); %>` which runs on *render* phase and directly outputs the value of the expression. As a result, it can't be used to modify behavior of server-side objects.

Comment: and the binding expression will only work on the page level if Page.DataBind() is called.

Comment: Well, `Page` inherits from `Control`, so that applies to it as a whole too. `DataBind` can be called on individual controls too.

Comment: Right. I think people are commonly confused when the put <%# expressions on a page and wonder why nothing shows up. For less experienced devs, its not immediately obvious that Page : Control and that it can have DataBind() called against it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all. Wish this kind of stuff would be better documented.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= %>` is the equivalent of `Response.Write();`

`<%# %>` is for databinding when calling `.DataBind();`