# How to use ASP.NET <%= tags in server control attributes?

Tags: asp.net, tags

This works:

```
<span value="<%= this.Text %>" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
<asp:Label Text="<%= this.Text %>" runat="server" />
```

Why is that?

How can I make the second case work properly, i.e., set the label's text to the value of the "Text" variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why will <%= %> expressions as property values on a server-controls lead to a compile errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how to mark this as such, but this is a bit of a duplicate.  [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-compile).

I don't think embedding code in to your markup will really make your markup any clearer or more elegant.

Comment: Late comment: I'd think that setting something like the text for a button to a simple variable or function makes more sense in the markup than in the code behind. Especially if you have many buttons set with text="literal", but one or two need some code, it's annoying that most are set in the markup but the exceptions are in the code behind. Now I not only have to look in two places to see the text values, but I have to search to find the place in the code behind. I certainly wouldn't put ten pages of code in the markup, but a simple "text=&lt;%=foo.bar%&gt; seems very useful. Whatever.

Comment: In the real world often getting something working trumps making something clearer or more elegant.

Answer (score 57):

Use [Data binding expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# DateTime.Now %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Code behind,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

you can do this

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ><%= variable%></asp:Label>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  No databind required.

Comment: This answer does not address the question which is specifically asking about attributes.

Answer (score 9):

In my code i am using something like this easily but in the databound control like ListView Item template

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="EditAction" class="actionLinks" Visible='<%#Eval("IsTrue").ToString() != "True"%>' runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ContentId","/articles/edit.aspx?articleid={0}")%>' />
```

But when i tried to use outside the databound control using <%# .. %>, it simply doesn't work.

You can easily do with

```
<a href="<%=myHref%>">My href</a>
```

But for server controls, and outside of databound control. We need to call DataBind() in pageload event explicitly

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="aa" NavigateUrl='<%#myHref%>' >
```

Comment: I agree. I tried using Hyperlink but the inline expression <%= > never worked. KISS, Keep it simple, and I used <a href> and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

You will need to set the value of the server control in code

First of all, assign an ID to the label control so you can access the control

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
```

Then, in your Page_Load function, set the value of your labels 'Text' field

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myLabel.Text = 'Whatever you want the label to display';
}
```

This function will be in your code behind file, or, if you are not using the code behind model, inside your aspx page you will need

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.Text = 'Whatever you want the label to display';
    }
</script>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

`<asp:Label>` is compiling at runtime and converting to html tags. You can set text with codebehind or like this:

```
<asp:Label id="Text1" runat="server" />
<% Text1.Text = this.Text;%>
```

**UPD:** Seems like my variant doesnt work, this is better:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    Text1.Text = this.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pitching this little nugget in for those who want a good technical breakdown of the issue -- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-and-in-asp-net/

I think the crux is in pretty decent agreement with the other answers:

> - The <%= expressions are evaluated at render time
> - The <%# expressions are evaluated at DataBind() time and are not evaluated at all if DataBind() is not called.
> - <%# expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls. <%= expressions cannot.