# Showing a variable in a label using <%= %>

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a `string` variable in the code behind and i want to show it in a label in html.

i know i can control the lable using the asp.net like this:

```
label.Text=stringVariable;
```

but i want to use this `<%= %>`,
here is what i have tired:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text='<%=stringVariable %>'></asp:Label>
```

*the stringVariable is a `public` kind of variable

but instead of showing my the variable, it shows:"<%=stringVariable %>" on the label.

how can i do this? Thanks for the help

Comment: since you have used '<%=stringVariable %>' within single quotes or double, it should treat as entire(normal) string instead of you trying to access the label text

Comment: You need to use Eval() function to get the value of the label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<asp:Label>` is compiling at runtime and converting to html tags. You can set text with code-behind or like this:

```html
<asp:Label id="Text1" runat="server" />
<% Text1.Text = stringVariable;%>
```

or

try `spam`  tag

```html
<span value="<%= stringVariable %>" />
```

More discussions

[How to use ASP.NET <%= tags in server control attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393348/how-to-use-asp-net-tags-in-server-control-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try, it might help you for your question

**<%# Eval("stringVariable ")%>**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text=" <%# Eval("stringVariable ")%>" > </asp:Label>
```

use single or double quotes based on requirements

Comment: are you getting value here "label.Text=stringVariable;" ??, if yes, then place "label.Text" instead of "stringVariable"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```html
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server"><%=stringVariable %></asp:Label>
```