# Quotes in my markup replaced with html entities?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a content page (using a master page) with a text box and a button. I want the button to call some javascript before doing anything else. Right now I'm just testing the javascript, so this is a rough draft.

The problem is that my markup is getting altered, so the client doesn't see all the quotes. Quotes are getting converted to HTML entity strings.

So the button in this code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInputTopics" 
            runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Width="335px" Height="250px" 
            CssClass="mediumFontTextbox"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnTestAdd" 
            runat="server" Text="Add"
            OnClientClick='CheckFirstAlphaNum(document.getElementById("<%= txtInputTopics.ClientID %>").val);'  />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Get's changed to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphMainContent$btnTestAdd"
   value="Add"
   onclick="CheckFirstAlphaNum(document.getElementById(&quot;&lt;%= txtInputTopics.ClientID %>&quot;).val);" 
   id="cphBody_cphMainContent_btnTestAdd" />
```

Why?

Comment: Having the quotes changed is not a problem. It's the failure to parse the `<%=` thing as ASP that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they should be HTML encoded. To include a quotation mark inside an attribute value that is delimited by quotation marks, it has to be HTML encoded. The client will see the quotation marks just fine.

Your problem is that you are trying to use a server code tag (`<%= txtInputTopics.ClientID %>`) inside an attribute in a control that has `runat="server"`. The code ends up literally in the HTML attribute instead of putting the client id value in the attribute.

You need another way of putting the value in the attribute, for example using a data binding expression. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393407/69083

Comment: I must have had an error somewhere else. I just got nervous when I saw the HTML tags instead of quotes. I can set the onclick correctly with this: btnTestAdd.OnClientClick = "CheckFirstAlphaNum($(" + txtInputTopics.ClientID + ").val(), 'Topic Name')";. My code is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by Guffa you need another method to get the input node, you can try to get the previous sibling of the button

```
//source: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp
function get_previoussibling(n) {
  x=n.previousSibling;
  while (x.nodeType!=1) {
    x=x.previousSibling;
  }
  return x;
}

function CheckFirstAlphaNum(element) {
  var inputEl = get_previoussibling(element);
  var value = inputEl.value;
  // do your stuff
}
```

html

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInputTopics" 
      runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
      Width="335px" Height="250px" 
      CssClass="mediumFontTextbox"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnTestAdd" 
      runat="server" Text="Add"
      OnClientClick="CheckFirstAlphaNum(this);" />
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```