# Unable to use server side delimiters inside title property

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The title in the below expression comes as a string instead of the evaluated expression.

```
<MY:Modal id="dialog_prePopChat" runat="server" ModalType="Dialog" Background="None" Title='<% MessageHelper.GetMessageText(283121) %>' />
```

The title shows like - '<% MessageHelper.GetMessageText(283121) %>'
Instead of - 'Live Help'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be number of posts closer to your ones on SO. For e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393348/how-to-use-asp-net-tags-in-server-control-attributes)

Comment: Further have read through of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co) for more detailed explanation on the usage of <% %>.