# Append a string in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have following code in my aspx page

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acknowledged_SLA")  %>' ID="lblStartDate"></asp:Label>
```

Its out put is a number say 2

I need to display as 2 days

I tried to append by using  + but not working

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work

```
Text='<%# Bind("Acknowledged_SLA")  %> days'
```

or

```
Text='<%# Bind("Acknowledged_SLA") + " days" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
<asp:Label runat="server"><%=Test %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: NOt working, It dispayed as <%# Bind("Acknowledged_SLA") %> days

Comment: check now. I had modified it.

Comment: Same as above, no difference

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393348/how-to-use-asp-net-tags-in-server-control-attributes