# Data binding along with the value in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How do you achive something like below in asp.net?

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="The '<%# CustomValue %>' you assigned."/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393348/how-to-use-asp-net-tags-in-server-control-attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it that way, write the string inside the server tags.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# "The " + CustomValue + " you assigned." %>'/>
```

However if the Label is not inside a GridView, Repeater etc you have to call `DataBind` manually.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This usually depends on where your Label resides. If it is a stond alone control, not nested inside a repeater, you just set your code in code behind:

```
Label1.Text = $"The {CustomValue} you assigned.";
```

If the label is nested inside an ItemTemplate in some sort of Repeater control, you can strongly type it to an objects property:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater" ItemType="WebFormsSandbox.Person">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="~/Persons/<%#:Item.Id%>"><%#: Item.FirstName %>  <%#: Item.LastName %></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the corresponding code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyRepeater.DataSource = Persons();
    MyRepeater.DataBind();
}

IEnumerable<Person> Persons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return new Person { Id= i, FirstName = $"Foo{i}", LastName = $"Bar{i}" };
    }
}
```

This would create a list of links, where you then  could do anything with it. Whether this would pop up a custom window or does a postback .. up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically do this in the code behind on page load, unless you were using a datagrid or repeater control. Assign an ID to your control and reference it like so.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    Label1.Text = "Your Value";
}
```

Comment: Think of the situation where you have got a grid and when you click on the row, a popup you want to show the custom value from row along with your text

Comment: So on the row click you don't need any further information, except what is in your row? If that is the case I would save yourself a trip to the server and just use a javascript approach, it can be accomplished pretty simply using something like jQuery. Add a click event to your row, find and get the required field value and display it in your popup.