# adding variables to Server tag

Tags: html, vb.net

Trying to add a vb.net variable to a button tag. I don't know the syntax. Where it says commandArgument I'm trying to reference the for loop.

```
<%For i = 0 To NumElements - 1%>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <b><%Response.Write((IdentityList.Item(i).ReportNumber))%></b>
    </td>
    <asp:Button
        ID="ButtonDetails" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Details"
        class="button buttonStyle"
        value="Details"
        CommandName="Identity"
        commandArgument="<%i%>"
        OnCommand="ButtonDetails_Click"
    />
    </tr>
<%Next%>
```

Comment: I don't know much about ASP.NET but I think it's: `"<%= i %>"`

Comment: That did not work. It thinks that <%=i%> is the actual argument not the variable itself. I tried using # too but I'm pretty sure that would reference the aspx.vb class, not the .aspx form itself as it couldn't find variable i.

Comment: See [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393407) in the duplicate. In addition to using `<%#  %>` you need to call `Me.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`.