# ASP.NET Usercontrol Property value does not run <%= markup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Well i have a usercontrol with a property "ClientScript" and in the aspx file where i use the usercontrol i set the value to `=document.getElementsByName('<%=ReportViewer1.ClientId %>$ctl01$ctl07$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00')[0].click(); return false;`

the problem here is that the is litterly passed to the property and not parsed first and replaced by the ClientID..

I had the same clientscript applied to a buttons OnClientClick and there it worked...

Must i apply some sort of attribute to the property to get this working?

here is my code:

Usercontrol.ascx.vb

```
<ParseChildren(True), PersistChildren(False), Themeable(False)>
Public Class CommandPanel
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private mClientScript as string
    <Themeable(False), DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Property ClientScript As String
        Get
            Return mClientScript
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mClientScript = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Page.aspx

```
<%@ Register src="UserControls/CommandPanel.ascx" tagname="CommandPanel" tagprefix="uc1" %>
......
<uc1:CommandPanel ID="CommandPanel1" runat="server" ClientScript="document.getElementsByName('<%= ReportViewer1.ClientId %>$ctl01$ctl07$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00')[0].click(); return false;" />
......
```

Note: i know that im saving to a local variable and that it will be cleared on reload and so on but thats not the problem here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= expressions cannot be used in server-side controls. You can use <%# syntax (then you must call DataBind on user control) or [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx) property.

Comment: What do you mean with can't be used in server-side controls? its not used in the usercontrol its used where the usercontrol in used if you understand what i mean? what makes my usercontrol diffrent from a button that hinders me from using <%=?

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx, http://kbalertz.com/976112/Introduction-inline-expressions-Framework.aspx. Can't find relevant MSDN docs.

Comment: Thanks for those links ill read them but the thing i don't get that it works with <%= in the <asp:buttons OnClientClick=... but not on my custom property...

Comment: Thanks now i think i get it some what atleast <%= is the same thing as <% Response.Write(... then it does make some what of a sense that i can't use it in my property... but the big question is still why does it work on the button control....

Comment: I think it's because their base classes are not same. Button inherits from WebControl, but user controls derive from, well....UserControl class.