# Passing dynamic variable to UserControl attribute

Tags: asp.net, variables, user-controls, attributes

I'm creating an UserControl and I'm passing a variable to it.

It works fine if I do it this way:

```
<uc:TestControl ID="testControl" runat="server" Variable="test"></uc:TestControl>
```

However I want to pass a dynamic variable to the control like this:

```
<uc:TestControl ID="testControl" runat="server" Variable="<%=dynamicVariable%>"></uc:TestControl>
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work and I know I could assign it on Page_Load but I don't like that way.

So I'm wondering if it's possible at all. Is there **any way** to assign a dynamic variable to an attribute like I wanted above? Or am I required to do it in Page_Load?

Any feedback would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%=` syntax doesn't work with controls marked as `runat="server"` .Try using the databind syntax

```
Variable="<%#dynamicVariable%>"
```

Then calling [databind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.databind.aspx) on the user control as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802901/asp-net-usercontrol-property-value-does-not-run-markup)

**EDIT**

To database i think it's a straight

```
testControl.DataBind()
```

supported in ASP.Net 3.5 and greater.

Comment: Hmmm I see, how exactly would I databind it?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I need to DataBind the control in Page_Load? Which is basically what I want to avoid :/

Comment: ah - yep. You get the syntax you want but ... you are into the server side. I think it's as close as you are going to get TBH. Someone else might know more

Comment: I resolved it, I just made the control itself DataBind in the overriden Render method. Thanks a lot for the help!