# Set literal text with inline code in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET project, I have a literal. In order to set the text property, I used the following code:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltUserName" runat="server" Text="<%= session.UserName %>" />
```

But instead of value of `session.UserName`, literal shows `<%= session.UserName %>`. I feel that solution is simple but I couldn't do it. How can set the text with inline code?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/370263/360171

Comment: So I made a mistake by choosing `<%= %>`. But I also couldn't do it with `<%# %>`. I couldn't find the correct way of setting literal text with inline code in aspx file.

Comment: actually you can do it with `<%# %>` and call `DataBind()` method on page.  Just try use `<%# %>` and add to `Page_Load` handler `this.DataBind()` method call

Comment: Thank you Yuriy, adding `this.DataBind();` to `Page_Load` solved exactly what I asked. I prefer removing literal for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want to print the session value in the HTML page just use 
    <% =Session["UserName"].ToString()%> as "<% %> will act as server tag and you cant give it inside the literal control

I mean no need of Literal Control can just use mentioned coding instead of literal.

Comment: Thanks, removing literal solved the problem. `Hello <%= session.UserName.ToString() %>` works great.

Comment: @sevenkul You don't need that extra `.ToString()` if UserName is a string.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax =<%# ... %> is Data binding syntax used to bind values to control properties when the DataBind method is called.

You need to call DataBind - either Page.DataBind to bind all the controls on your page, or this.DataBind() to bind just the label. E.g. add the following to your Page_Load event handler:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltUserName" runat="server"  Text='<%# Session["UserName"]%>'></asp:Literal>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = "Sample";
        this.DataBind(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried:

```
Text='<%= session.UserName %>'
```

Single quotes may solve it

**EDIT:**

Based on this thread: stackoverflow.com/a/370263/360171

I would simply replace

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltUserName" runat="server" Text="<%= session.UserName %>" />
```

by

```
<%= session.UserName %>
```

Comment: It still prints <%= session.UserName %>.

Comment: If you're having a hard time, why dont you do `ltUserName.Text = session.UserName` at code behind? Im having no problems here, btw

Comment: I was using `ltUserName.Text = session.UserName` and it was working fine but I wanted to keep clean my codebehind. I think I am having a hard time as you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix controls (`<asp:Literal />`) with code blocks (`<%= .. %>`).

You can access the Text property from within code:

```
 ltUserName.Text = session.UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Renatos answer is correct, you should put single quotes when you are going to evaluate an expression in a property.

The same can be said with a `ItemTemplate`, where you have controls to databind, where you would use `Text='<%=Eval("MyDataProperty")%>'`.