# How to write <%%> in server controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to use `<%=%>` in server controls but it isn't working.
This is my code:

```
 <input type="button" runat="server" value="<< Previous" id="btnPrevious" 
        onclick="location.href='<%=PreviousLink %>'"/>
```

`PreviousLink` is property defined in page.
When I view the page the whole expression is written as it without being evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can define it in your controller code:

```
btnPrevious.OnClientClick = "location.href='" + PreviousLink + "'"
```

Comment: Exactly... you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Using jQuery:**

```
<input type="button" runat="server" value="<< Previous" id="btnPrevious"/>
<script>
$(function () {
            $("#<%=btnPrevious.ClientID%>").on("click", function (event) {
                window.location.href = '<%=PreviousLink %>';
            });
});
</script>
```

**Using JavaScript:**

```
function onButtonClick() {
        window.location.href = '<%=PreviousLink %>';
    }

<input type="button" runat="server" value="<< Previous" id="btnPrevious" onclick="onButtonClick();"/>
```

**.aspx.cs (C# code):**

```
public string PreviousLink = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `runat server` attribute then <% %> expression will get evaluated properly.
Check this question
[Why will <%= %> expressions as property values on a server-controls lead to a compile errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co)

Answer (score 0):

That should work too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setLocation() {
  location.href = '<%=PreviousLink %>';
}
</script>
<input type="button" runat="server" value="<< Previous" id="btnPrevious" onclick="setLocation();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use an ASP.NET inline expression to set the value during the loading of the page.

First, add a property in the code-behind of your page.

```
protected string InputValue { get; set; }
```

In the `Page_Load` event, set the value of the property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.InputValue = "something";
    }
}
```

Finally, add an inline expression in your page markup like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txt" value="<%= this.InputValue %>" />
```

This will let you set the value of the `input` element without making it a server-side tag.