# How to pass Query string using embedded code block?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass query string value on clicking any hyperlink which are dnamically generated. Something like this..

```
<%
------some code----
 clickedalbum = dt6.Rows[0]["albumid"].ToString();

  %> 
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" href="attendance1.aspx?albumid=<%#clickedalbum %>" >
```

Comment: make sure clickedalbum  is global variable in the page class with public attripute

Comment: yes it is  public string clickedalbum="";

Comment: what the error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error i am just getting what i want. This is the resulting url which i am getting on running above code 
abc.aspx?albumid=%3C%#clickedalbum%20%%3E

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out, the problem was that i was using server control. 
Using
 `<a href='attendance1.htm?albumid=<%=clickedalblum%>'>--some stuff--</a>`
Solved the problem. Thanks everyone for their response specially Ratna.

Answer (score 0):

Do it from code behind in load event as

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "attendance1.aspx?albumid=" + clickedalbum;
```

ok do it as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#clickedalbum %>' Text="Testlink"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code behind:

```
using System;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 public string clickedalbum = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     clickedalbum = "attendance1.aspx?albumid=123";
     DataBind();
}
}
```

For details visit this link [Why will <%= %> expressions as property values on a server-controls lead to a compile errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co)

Comment: can i just pass it from aspx itself?

Comment: do as avove, First copy paste whole code in a new page, then play with it.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
href='<%# "attendance1.aspx?albumid="+clickedalbum %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("clickedalbum ","~/attendance1.aspx?albumid={0}") %>'
```

Comment: still same. Output with your code:
..../albumid=%3C%#clickedalbum%20%%3E