# Embedded code (<%= %>) in button control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project where I'm using the `<%= getString("key")%>` to dynamically get the appropriate text.

this works great when i use it in simple p tags, but i can't find a way to do this with controls like Button/Label etc.

Is there any way, other than calling

```
Mybutton.Text = getstring("key");
```

to dynamically add the text?

The idea is that getString retrieves af language code, and depending on that code gets a string in the appropiate language.

I've been looking around, but all i come across is using the embedded code tags directly in the aspx pages, which wont cut it for buttontext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use DataBinding instead of the `<%=` operator, you can use:

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" Text='<%# getstring("key") %>' />
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co) is a good explanation of why `<%=` won't work in this context.