# ASP.NET dynamic image url using server tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms

I am trying to set the ImageUrl using the following code...

```
<asp:Image ID="brokenImage" runat="server" AlternateText="Coded path" ImageUrl='~/headerImages/<%= getImage(Request.QueryString["Id"]) %>'/>
```

Eliminating the opening tag and viewing the browser ouput alongside an image tag that is explicitly written produces the following results....

```
asp:Image ID="brokenImage" runat="server" AlternateText="Coded path" ImageUrl='~/headerImages/images (3).jpg' />

asp:Image ID="workingImage" runat="server" AlternateText="Explicit Path" ImageUrl="~/headerImages/images (3).jpg" />
```

Why is the first image not displaying but the second is? How can I pass a parameter to the code behind and set the url?

Comment: If the *browser output* includes `asp:Image` tags then something much more fundamental is broken here.  That would indicate that your web server isn't doing server-side ASP.NET processing.

Comment: is query string holding the extension of the image like .jpg or id only ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for correct way to do this, your markup should be :

```
<asp:Image ID="brokenImage" runat="server" AlternateText="Coded path" ImageUrl='<%# "~/headerImages/" + getImage(Request.QueryString["Id"]) %>'/>
```

And in the code you should have this:

```
brokenImage.DataBind();
```

**Explanation:** `<%= %>` outputs directly to the response stream. And `<%# %>` evaluates the code when you bind the control. Very nice and short explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370263/690329).