# How to use a constant definde in a .vb file as the id for an element in an .ascx page?

Tags: vb.net, tags, constants, ascx

Let's say I have a `Constants` class defined in a `.vb` file as such:

```
Public Const myConst As String = "myID"
```

And in my `page.ascx` file I wish to do something like this:

```
...
<someControl ID="<%$ Constants.myConst %>" runat="server" />
...
```

This shields compilation errors all over the place.

I've attempted several combinations, including `=` or `#` instead of `$`, but none seem to work.

Note that I've read and do not believe this to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co) answer, nor other similars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is even possible since Visual Studio use the ID to create an instance of that object in the .vb file. I would question the purpose of this but if you really need to I would suggest to generate a dictionary.

```
<someControl ID="ctrlName" runat="server" />
```

And in the init

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Control)

dic.Add(Constants.myConst, ctrlName)
```

Usually it's the other way around where the web page tells the dll which id/instance to use.

Comment: Yes, I've just had confirmation from someone with expertise that this is not doable. It is not possible to do this.