# How to add a string variable to a asp:label Text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, label

```
<% string **testString** = "Hello"; %>

<asp:label runat="server" ID="test123" *Text*="<% =**testString** %> "/>
```

how can i add a variable to the *Text* part in the `label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variable like this

```
protected string abc;
```

and then assign value in page_load

```
abc= "test";
DataBind();
```

your aspx:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# abc%>' />
```

Comment: i get the output as <%= testString %>

Comment: i copy pasted the code according to the instructions you gave me and still i get the output as : <%= abc%> not test :(

Comment: sorry my bad, i forgot to update the Text property of label..now test it again and it'll work

Comment: are you binding data after assigning value to variable?
and if its possible please share your code.

Comment: It worked after using DataBind(); Thanks alot for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= YourVariable %>' ID="test123" />
```

This is a bit of a duplicate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co) thread.

Comment: Show our asxp code and show your variable you declared and initialized

Comment: i am getting the output as:  <% testString%> not Hello. The Varable is in <% string testString ="Hello" %>