# Prevent Embedded ASP Code from being escaped

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

This one looks similar to the question that is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co) but the scenario asked by the OP looks different as his accepted answer do does not meet my requirement.In my case, I am trying to embed an asp snippet as parameter of a Javascript method called from an `onclick`  of button , but the result is that the tags gets escaped when compiled. The ASP code is :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Calculate_Mean" Text="Calculate Mean" 
OnClientClick="mean('<%$TextBoxA.ClientID + ',' + TextBoxB.ClientID + ',' +
TextBoxC.ClientID%>')"
```

The Outcome I got is:

```
<input type="submit" name="Calculate_Mean" 
value="Calculate Mean"
onclick="mean(&#39;&lt;%=TextBoxA.ClientID%>&#39;);" id="Calculate_Mean" />
```

I've referred and tried the following pages but still couldn't solve the issue:

[Passing ASP.net control to JS Function](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/84113/How-to-pass-asp-net-textbox-control-to-JavaScript)

[Different Embedded ASP Code Blocks and its uses](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Different-Embedded-Code-Blocks-and-its-use-in-ASPNet.aspx)

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the rendered page:
[image: Screenshot of Page rendered]

Comment: Why use  $ ? <%$   , must be <%=

Comment: Yes bro, I tried all the types of tags but the resultant is same

Comment: What is the file extension of your page?

Comment: @Schalk.Netgen  its `.aspx`

Comment: Server-side code appearing commented out normally means that it's not getting processed - and the reason for this is normally using the wrong file extension. My speciality is ASP.NET/Razor so I wish I could help more, but I'd suggest looking for the issue somewhere else than the embedded code.

Can you post a screenshot of your inspected page with the code in question highlighted?

Comment: @Schalk.Netgen yes bro, as you requested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why will <%= %> expressions as property values on a server-controls lead to a compile errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can change asp:button for a html button:

```
<button  onclick="mean( document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxA.ClientID%>'));" ></button>
```

Or try getting client ids inside js function:

ASPX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mean() {
            var a = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxA.ClientID%>');
            var b = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxB.ClientID%>');
            var c = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxC.ClientID%>');
            alert(a.value);
            alert(b.value);
            alert(c.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxA" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxB" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxC" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Calculate_Mean" Text="Calculate Mean" 
        OnClientClick="mean();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but can't it be injected as a parameter to the called js cuntion because this mean will be called by several inputs that resides as table rows?
For instance: `mean(txtbox1, txtbox2,txtbox3)` and `mean(txtbox4, txtbox5,txtbox6)`

Comment: @thecodingpanda can you change for a html button ? Check my update

Comment: Thanks @Mate, `<button onclick="mean('<%=TextBoxA.ClientID%>');"></button>` looked neat and did the trick :)