# Disable hyperlink in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Right, please don't point me there:
[Disable a HyperLink from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413754/disable-a-hyperlink-from-code-behind)

My problem is as follows. 
I have a hyperlink on my aspx page:

```
<asp:HyperLink Visible='<%= _myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management")%>' Text="Intranet Management" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/Apps/Admin/Default.aspx" />
```

`_myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management")` returns boolean with value of TRUE or FALSE depends if a current user has that permission or not. _myUser is declared in aspx.cs file as protected member so I am able to access it from aspx file.

On my page I am getting following error:

> Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean'
>   from its string representation '<%= _myUser.hasPermission("Intranet
>   Management") %>' for the 'Visible' property.

Is there any other way of doing that in aspx file? Please don't ask me to do it in the code behind, I have my reasons to do it here...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please tell the reasons? If you want to do something the wrong way, please provide at least why

Comment: At some point I will be using sql data source to populate list of links using repeater, and instead of "Intranet Management" etc I will be passing an app name pulled from DB...

Comment: That is still not a reason. It is meant to be done from code behind as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `asp:Hyperlink` is a server control, and these wont evaluate code inside `<%= %>` for their properties. They will databind though IIRC, so you could try

```
<asp:HyperLink Visible='<%# _myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management")%>'...
```

And make sure to call `Page.DataBind()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I ended up using different approach after all but I am marking your reply as answer anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to do it this way, you cannot have `runat="server"`. The idea is that server-side controls will be modified using code behind.

If you don't want to use code behind, use a regular `<a>` tag without `runat="server"`. There doesn't seem to really be any reason why you need a server control here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

use the following instead:

```
<%# _myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management") %>
```

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369736/assigning-visible-property-of-the-button-to-a-static-method-result)

Answer (score 1):

This should work ...

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(_myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management")) %>' Text="Intranet Management" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/Apps/Admin/Default.aspx" />
```

Perhaps this is better after all

```
<a style='<%= Convert.ToBoolean(_myUser.hasPermission("Intranet Management")) ? "" : "display:none;" %>' href="Apps/Admin/Default.aspx"> Intranet Management </a>
```